# How to assert range for password_length

Tags: rspec, devise

User.password_length gives me 11..256, how do I assert it

```
  it do
    expect(User.password_length).to be_between(11, 256)
  end
```

But I am getting this

```
Failure/Error: expect(User.password_length).to be_between(11, 256)
       expected 11..256 to be between 11 and 256 (inclusive), but it does not respond to `<=` and `>=`
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:45:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # -e:1:in `<main>'
```

**I don't understand what does not respond to <= and >=**

Comment: what is `password_length`? Can you show your full model implementation?

Comment: Standard devise configuration @meta

Comment: try `expect(User.password_length).to be_a(Fixnum)` - I'm guessing its  not what you think it is.